# A simple one-dimensional non-dispersive Wave-equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, waves, wavefunction

I have been trying to follow the steps to solve a problem in a book about Physical Chemistry; a major part of which is about Quantum Mechanics.
One of the problem examples is to show that this wave function
$\left(Asin\left(kx-\omega t+\phi \right)\right)$
is a solution for a one dimensional non-dispersive wave equation, and the relattion between v with k and $\omega $.

The one dimensional non-dispersive wave equation being:
$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\psi \left(x,t\right)\right)=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial \:^2}{\partial \:t^2}\left(\psi \:\left(x,t\right)\right)$

I have tried to follow the steps in the book which are:

$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\psi \left(x,t\right)\right)=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial \:^2}{\partial \:t^2}\left(\psi \:\left(x,t\right)\right)$

$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}\left(Asin\left(kx-\omega +\phi \:\right)\right)=-k^2Asin\left(kx-\omega \:t+\phi \:\right)$

$\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}\left(Asin\left(kx-\omega t+\phi \:\right)\right)=\frac{-\omega ^2}{v^2}=Asin\left(kx-\omega \:t+\phi \:\right)$

I find the second derivative with respect to $t$ and also understand that $k=w/v$. But I don't understand where the $t$ disappears in the second row left side, as well as the third row of the explanation.

What I get in the end is $\left(Asin\left(kx-\omega t+\phi \right)\right)$ cancelling itself out on both sides and you're left with w/v=k.

Comment: I think the disappearing t is just a typo

Comment: @infinitezero after staring at it for about a day I think so too. But what is the last part   $=Asin\left(kx-\omega \:t+\phi \:\right)$? and why did they put it at the end?

Comment: There is another typo in the last line. The last equality sign should not be there. So the equation should read: $\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}\left(Asin\left(kx-\omega t+\phi \:\right)\right)=\frac{-\omega ^2}{v^2}Asin\left(kx-\omega \:t+\phi \:\right)$